# Como limitar um usuário a acessar apenas os seus próprios dados?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-jpa

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação de lista de tarefas para estudo, porém, todos os usuários acessam todas as tarefas.

Gostaria de saber se alguém já implementou algo do tipo com o **Spring Security** e como fez.

Comment: Fez o sistema de login?
As tarefas registradas no banco estão associadas a um único usuário? Se sim, pega o usuário logado e mostra só as tarefas dele, como a query que o colega ai já deu.

Comment: Como estão suas tabelas ? Possui algum relacionmamento de Usuario a Tarefas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer todo o trabalho manualmente, adicionando uma cláusula `AND usuario_id = :id_usuario_autenticado"` como dito em uma das respostas.

Uma outra estratégia é usar multi-tenancy, que é basicamente uma forma de isolar os dados dos usuários em tabelas ou instâncias separadas. O Spring tem suporte a isso de algumas maneiras. Eu pessoalmente nunca usei, mas seguem alguns exemplos, tutoriais e explicações:

https://marcelosouzavieira.wordpress.com/2016/04/26/spring-boot-bunny-multi-tenancy/

https://www.ricston.com/blog/multitenancy-jpa-spring-hibernate-part-1/

https://github.com/rcandidosilva/spring-boot-multitenant

Answer (score 0):

Você não necessariamente precisaria utilizar algum recurso de segurança para isso.

De uma maneira mais simples, imaginando que você possua um processo de autenticação na sua aplicação, após autenticar e identificar o usuário que acessou a aplicação, as informações desse usuário você pode recuperar através de algum ID (código do usuário ou ID na base de dados) associado a esses seus registros. Da seguinte maneira:

```
... FROM Tarefas t WHERE t.usuario_id = :id_usuario_autenticado
```

Essa minha sugestão está considerando que você já possui algum modo de diferenciar os usuários (ID) e, pela sua pergunta, você está recuperando as informações da base de dados sem considerar essa diferença.

Comment: Tenho processo de autenticação sim. Pensei em fazer algo manualmente mas antes queria saber se o framework resolve isso de algum jeito.

Comment: Entendi. Mas ficou claro para você essa ideia de associar os registros na base de dados com o ID do usuário? Porque acredito que esse ponto pode te ajudar a iniciar nessa separação de dados. Você pode utilizar segurança, por exemplo, autorização para acessar determinados recursos, mas para recuperar somente os recursos de um usuário específico isso pode ser feito através do ID do mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode limitar a exibição de algum conteúdo na página usando o Spring Security Dialect do Thymeleaf.

Limitando o conteúdo usando roles:

```
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">This content is only shown to administrators.</div>
```

https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html